# CK editor and missing image URL

Tags: php, fckeditor

I have integrated [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com) with my admin panel (php)
I have writtien a function for calling editor:

```
function editor(){
$txt = '<script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace( "kabst",{
            filebrowserUploadUrl : "'.UPLOAD_SCRIPT.'" });                          
            </script>';
    return $txt;
}
```

and define:

```
 define("UPLOAD_SCRIPT", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cms/dashboard/upload.php");
```

I have error: NOT FOUND in ck upload. But upload.php is working. What is wrong in my code? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, where does this error show up? Is that the full text?

Comment: when uploading image with ckeditor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use $_SERVER['SERVER_ROOT'] instead of DOCUMENT_ROOT ?

Comment: With 'SERVER_ROOT' its ok but with clicking "ok" there is an error : Image source URL is missing.

Comment: Never heard of that error before to be honest, but sounds like it's getting the wrong path of the uploaded file. Maybe you can find something about it on google